# Is it possible to install Visual Studio in AWS EC2 Windows instance using Remote Desktop connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, rdp

I want to move my Data Warehouse Project from desktop to the cloud. I have installed Windows Sever instance using AWS Free Tier Acount.But I want to install Visual Studio on it.Is it get charged? or is it free on Free Tier? Is it possible?Please help me.

Comment: You do mean Visual Studio (paid), not Visual Studio Code (free), right?

Comment: Instead of using IDE on the cloud machine, it is better to use Git.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is it possible to install Visual Studio on Amazon EC2 Windows Server via RDP.
A: I don't see why not. It's Windows. You can install apps on Windows.

Q: Is there a cost to do this?
A: AWS has nothing to do with Visual Studio pricing. You should investigate whether or not the Visual Studio license allows for non-Microsoft cloud installation and what their pricing is. You may be able to leverage your existing license for non-concurrent use, for example. If you actually mean Visual Studio Code rather than Visual Studio, then that's free.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. You can run Windows with the FREE-Tier and install Visual Studio (with you licence).

Maybe you should check "Cloud9" as IDE in the Web from AWS as alternative. Using Visual Studio Code on t2.micro via Remote Desktop will be... clunky and slow.